# Magento 2.3 - Updating a customer without store_id sets the store_id to default using REST

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3, rest-api, store-view

There are **multiple store views** in my site. I created a **customer** and set his store view to some value that is not the default.

Use the rest **api** to change the first name of the customer (Like: put to `PUT rest/V1/customers/8`)

I used the following body

```
{ "customer":         {
            "id": 1,
            "group_id": 1,
            "default_billing": "0",
            "default_shipping": "0",
            "created_at": "2019-05-13 14:33:11",
            "updated_at": "2019-05-13 14:33:11",
            "created_in": "alternate store view",
            "email": "xxx@redacted.com",
            "firstname": "firstname alternate",
            "lastname": "lastname",
            "gender": 0,
            "website_id": 1,
            "addresses": [],
            "disable_auto_group_change": 0
        }
}
```

So All the fields not passed in the PUT call are not changed (Including store_id) but it changed the store_id to default store_id.

I need to know why it changed the `store_id`, is `store_id` is mandatory if yes then why it does not show the error or it just save with default store_id if store_id not given in the request.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using this endpoint

"PUT rest/V1/customers/8"

means you are calling the default store view, So if you want to set another store id you have to use another endpoint like this

"PUT rest/**{store_code}**/V1/customers/8"

the above endpoint will set the correct store_id depending on the store code